# Checking if image exists produces 403 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have a range of hosted images, but the amount and url can change. However, they always follow the same incrementing naming convention. In order to store the images that exist, I loop through the available images until I encounter an error. At that point I store the results and continue with the operations.

```
function checkForExistingImage(u, r = [], i = 0){

    var url = u + i;

    $.get(url).done(function() { 
        r.push(url);
        checkForExistingImage(u, r, i + 1);
    }).fail(function(){
        //continue working with the 'r' array
    });
}
```

However, this will always result in a 403 (Image not found) error in the console, because the last image checked will never exist.

How can I not trigger this error, or maybe suppress it if needed?

Comment: 403 indicates forbidden, not found is 404. Are you sure the place you're accessing from has permission form host?

Comment: The error looks like a fundamental part of the approach you're taking to find out what images exist. You could always implement some server-side method that returns the actual number so that you don't have to probe for them from the client.

Comment: @Gavin Yes, I can find the existing images fine, it's just that when I go over the limit, I produce an error.

Comment: @Pointy I sadly don't have the access to a back-end system, but instead only a tag manager

Comment: Agreed with Pointy, the error is the condition that breaks the recursion. If you want to keep the existing logic but suppress the error you could try wrapping the call to checkForExistingImage in a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely rewrite this in a more civilised manner. This function does not log any errors outside of those that are explicitly logged by `console.log` (which you can remove).

It should be safer to use this as it does not bombard the server with too many requests per second, but you can reduce or remove the timeout if that's not a problem.

```
function Timeout(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, time);});
}

async function checkForExistingImages(baseUrl, maxImages, startImage = 0) {
  const results = [];
  // Some sanity check on params
  if(maxImages < startImage) {
    let tmp = maxImages;
    maxImages = startImage + 1;
    startImage = maxImages;
  }
  // from i to max
  for(let i=startImage; i<maxImages; ++i) {
    // Create image URL, change this as needed
    const imageURL = baseUrl + i + ".png";
    // `fetch` does not throw usually, but we wanted to avoid errors in console
    try {
      // Response will have 200/404/403 or something else
      const response = await fetch(imageURL);
      if(response.status == 200) {
        results.push(imageURL);
      }
      else {
        console.info("Image",imageURL,"was removed.");
        // stop loading
        break;
      }
    }
    // complete failure, some major error occured
    catch(e) {
      console.warn("Image",imageURL, "failed to send request!");
      break;
    }
    // If you're getting throttled by the server, use timeout
    await Timeout(200);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the answer. My problem is that I don't know the max. It could be 3, 4, 9 or 10 images. So I iterate to max+1, and when I get the error, I know I should stop. However, the error logs then, which is all I don't want.

Comment: @Davy The `maxImages` can be `Infinity`, I just included it when I was testing the answer. As you can see, under `console.info("Image",imageURL,"was removed.");` it will break and not load any more. The code above will however not produce any errors. You can remove the `console.log`, it's just for testing.